# Блокировки и перенаправления с ресурса

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Программировал в своем веб-проекте, и заметил такую фичу, что идут перенаправления с одной страницы на другую. Пишу проект на своем движке, в разделе нордические знакомства http://the-solarwind.ru/index.php?url=nord-love идут переадресации на страницы http://the-solarwind.ru/index.php?url=audiobooks&page=10 которых даже нет в системе (это о странице 10).

В социальной сети Вконтакте и в знакомствах Мамбы заметил такую же дрянь переадресации адресов от реальных людей к каким-то виртуальным страницам поиска. В чьих руках контроль за системой? Кто может в принципе так методично и настойчиво вредить мне в разделе поиска любви?

Кто-нибудь с такой ерундой сталкивался? Меня блоируют что ли как личность в сети или что?

Comment: Расширение в браузере?

Comment: Очень вероятно что и так, на Сафари с iPad такого не наблюдается.